# Angular: Invalidate bootstrap input using cross-field validation

Tags: angular, validation, bootstrap-4

I have two fields in my reactive form, `from` and `to`. I need to validate, whether `from` is lower than `to` right after the value of any is changed. For validation I use this cross-field validation:

```
var myForm = new FormGroup({
  from: new FormControl(fromValue),
  to: new FormControl(toValue)
}, { validators: [this.checkFromIsLowerThanTo] });

checkFromIsLowerThanTo(group: FormGroup): any {
  const from = Number(group.get('from').value);
  const to = Number(group.get('to').value);

  return from >= to ? { lowerIsHigherThanUpper: true } : null;
}
```

The template contains this:

```
<div *ngIf="range.hasError('lowerIsHigherThanUpper')">
  Lower bound is higher than upper
</div>
```

This part works perfectly - warning is shown as expected. But I'd also like to show that the fields themselves are not correct - highlight them with red colour.

The form has `class="was-validated"` and the field has `.custom-select:valid` (and also `.custom-select.is-valid`; the pseudo-class has precedence), so the two fields have green border (and green shadow when they are focused):

[image: from_to]

I'd like to find some way how to 'invalidate' (change `:valid` to `:invalid`) them within the validator. There is `setCustomValidity` function, but I haven't found any solution how to use this in the validator.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just write some additional CSS? Something like

```
.ng-invalid .custom-select {
    // styles here
}
```

Comment: Well, this would be the last option - one always want to use stuff, which is already finished, tested etc. Additionally, the added styles would never be as deep and good as the pre-built ones.

Comment: @Frimlik all your comments apply just as well to writing additional TypeScript.